# RCpp Temporary Build Location

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

I work in an environment where linking of dynamic libraries are restricted to certain locations.  When I use RStudio and request a new C++ file I get the "Hello World" template.  When I try to compile that and link that in by clicking on "Source" in RStudio, I get an error:

```
LoadLibrary failure: Access is denied.
```

This error is because the library was located in a space which is not allowed to be able to load DLL files.  To maneuver around this limitation, I would like to determine how to tell RCpp to place the temporary dll's (not in a package) in a specific location.

I know that Dirk has suggested that this is not in the scope of RCpp and that all code should live in packages, but that will not be he most user friendly environment for the users here.  I suspect that most will use RStudio projects with GIT.

So, that being said, is there an environment variable that I can mangle to get RCpp to place temporary dll files in a specific place.  Or is there some other mechanism which I can use to alter this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `TMPDIR` which R respects. This is indeed not an Rcpp issue but a generic `R CMD build` / `R CMD INSTALL` issue.

From `help(tempfile)`:

> The environment variables `TMPDIR`, `TMP` and `TEMP` are checked in
>        turn and the first found which points to a writable directory is
>        used: if none succeeds `/tmp` is used.

PS Rcpp with lower-case C.